# orderBy in recursive select query (typo3 / typoscript)

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a problem ordering the results from a recursive select-query.
It's just about ordering 2 levels of pages. I want the result to look like this:

- Parent 1

  - Child 1-1
  - Child 1-2
- Parent 2

  - Child 2-1
  - Child 2-2
  - Child 2-3

In my results I want one parent page followed by its children, then the next parent's page followed by its children and so on.
When using `orderBy = sorting`, I seem to get the results in a kind of "random" order, because it's sorting all the entries by the "sorting" field. It is ignoring if the result is a parent or a child-page of the result.
If I don't use `orderBy` at all, I get the parent's pages first, then the child's pages (maybe this is just a random result).

How can I sort my results correctly? 
(I've been thinking about a workaround, using `HMENU` or `TMENU` to display my results in the correct order)

Here's my typoscript:

```
table=pages
select{
  pidInList={leveluid:1}
  pidInList.insertData=1
  recursive=1
  orderBy=sorting
  max=200
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to nest the SELECT queries.
If you have the result cached, it's the same anyways ;)

```
tmp.data = CONTENT
tmp.data {
    table = pages
    select {
        pidInList.data = leveluid:1
        orderBy = sorting
        max = 200
    }

    renderObj = CONTENT
    renderObj {
        table = pages
        select {
            pidInList.field = uid
            orderBy = sorting
        }
    }
}
```